# Is the subdomain _acme-challenge protected?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, certificate-authority, lets-encrypt

I was looking into the DNS-01 challenge of Let's Encrypt; and I had a question about the sub domain process [1].

Let's say, the website example.com gives away free subdomains; what stops me to request a Let's Encrypt wildcard certificate for *.example.com, by claiming the _acme-challenge.example.com subdomain to process the DNS-01 challenge?

Is there anything in the ACME protocol (or anything else) that stops me from doing this?

[1] = https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, sites providing free/custom subdomains are providing `A` records, whereas the ACME DNS-01 challenge requires adding a `TXT` record. This would make what you suggest **very unlikely**.

If a site allows adding arbitrary `TXT` records for subdomains and doesn't reserve the `_acme-challenge`, then there's nothing in the protocol that would prevent abusing such a feature, and it would be a vulnerable service. However, that's a use case so uncommon that no-one would exclusively consider that when designing protocols like this.

Luckily, if this happens, Let's Encrypt certificates will expire in three months, and it's also possible to [revoke the certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/revoking/#using-a-different-authorized-account) even without access to its private key, just for cases like this:

> If someone issued a certificate after compromising your host or your
>   DNS, you’ll want to revoke that certificate once you regain control.
>   In order to revoke the certificate, Let’s Encrypt will need to ensure
>   that you control the domain names in that certificate (otherwise
>   people could revoke each other’s certificates without permission)! To
>   validate this control, Let’s Encrypt uses the same methods it uses to
>   validate control for issuance: you can put a value in a DNS TXT
>   record or put a file on an HTTP server. - -
>
> Once you’ve validated control of all the domain names in the
>   certificate you want to revoke, you can download the certificate
>   from crt.sh, then proceed to revoke the certificate as if you had
>   issued it:
>
> ```
> certbot revoke --cert-path /PATH/TO/downloaded-cert.pem
> ```

Comment: Very clear, thank you. I. first thought it needed to host a text file on that domain. But apparently there is also a thing called DNS TXT record which I did not know about.